# "bind: Address already in use" when creating bridge on Linux for Windows

Tags: ssh, bridge, windows-subsystem-for-linux

On Bash for Windows (WSL), I'm trying to create an SSH bridge, using the following command:

```
ssh -l ubuntu -L 15555:<ip1>:22 <ip2>
```

but I'm getting an error `bind: Address already in use` at this point:

```
Authenticated to <ip2> ([<ip2>]:22).
debug1: Local connections to LOCALHOST:15555 forwarded to remote address <ip1>:22
debug3: channel_setup_fwd_listener: type 2 wildcard 0 addr NULL
debug3: sock_set_v6only: set socket 4 IPV6_V6ONLY
debug1: Local forwarding listening on ::1 port 15555.
debug2: fd 4 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug3: fd 4 is O_NONBLOCK
debug1: channel 0: new [port listener]
debug1: Local forwarding listening on 127.0.0.1 port 15555.
bind: Address already in use
```

I've tried the same command on Ubuntu and Cygwin and it works, but I just can't get it to work on WSL. I've also tried different ports without any success and I didn't see anything that could be causing this on netstat.

Any idea what could be the reason?

Comment: Typo: your command mentions port `13333`, your trace mentions port `15555`. Besides, could it be that Windows security layer prevents you from opening a listening port on the local machine? Else, "already in use" means that another program is using the exact same port 15555. DId you launch your ssh command twice?

Comment: Yes sorry I've updated the question, it's because i've tried several ports 13333, 14444, etc. It could indeed be some issue with Windows security layer, however I managed to get Apache and MySQL running so some services definitely manage to listen on some ports.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
ssh -l ubuntu -L 127.0.0.1:15555:<ip1>:22 <ip2>
```

Or this:

```
ssh -l ubuntu -4 -L 15555:<ip1>:22 <ip2>
```

The problem is that it binds to the IPv6 address by default. This was already reported as a bug [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/BashOnWindows/issues/674) and solved in BashOnWindows
build 14942.

Comment: Yes that was it, the second line solved it, thanks a lot!